# How to code drop-down list properly in kivy-language?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I'm testing the drop-down list in order to get rid of some buttons in another code of mine but i can't make it work. On kivy's main web page the explanation is really shallow principaly when talking about the kv lang.

What i wanna do is [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_images/dropdown.gif), with fewer buttons. But i'd like to do it in kv lang. In my test code the drop-down list comes "opened" but it really doesn't show anything. You have to click on the slice of text that should be a button for it to close and than it won't open anymore.

How do i code this properly?

Heres my kv code:

```
<CustomDropDown>:

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'hello'
        on_release: dropdown.open(self)

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown
        size_hint_y: None
        on_select: btn.text = "{}".format(args)
        Button:
            text: 'btn 1'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)

        Button:
            text: 'btn 2'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)

        Button:
            text: 'btn 3'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class CustomDropDown(Widget):
    pass


class TestesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomDropDown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestesApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `CustomDropDown` and store it as a `Property` of a `Widget` in the `kv`, then `open()` it whenever you want. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

FloatLayout:
    Button:
        dropdown: Factory.CustomDropDown()
        id: btn
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 44
        text: 'hello'
        on_release: self.dropdown.open(self)

<CustomDropDown@DropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    size_hint_y: None
    on_select: app.root.ids.btn.text = "{}".format(args[1])
    Button:
        text: 'btn 1'
        on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44

    Button:
        text: 'btn 2'
        on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44

    Button:
        text: 'btn 3'
        on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
'''


class TestesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestesApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could just clear one thing for me, why did you import Factory?Also, how would you approach a case where you gotta have multiple dropdowns?

Comment: The `Factory` is required to create the `CustomDropDown` instance. You can do this as many times as you want. Just add another `Button` with another `dropdown` (maybe `CustomDropDown2`) and add another rule for `CustomDropDown2`.

Comment: Well i guess that solves it. I was looking for a more general solution as if could define it only once and then use it as many times as i wanted without having to redo the process of creating a class. I was studing and another way that i've found was to custom the `Spinner` from kivy. Problem with that is you can't modify the dropdown, or at least i don't know hot to. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The `<CustomDropDown@DropDown>` rule defines the `CustomDropDown` once. And it can be used as many times as you want. You can `Factory.CustomDropDown()` as many times as you like.